# UISlider: changed hight, but maximum value flashes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uislider

I customised a `UISlider` and everything works well except when I drag the slider to 100%. Then the rounded caps are replaced with a square.

Here is how I customize the Slider:

```
@IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 14

override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: trackHeight))
}
```

**98% image:**

[image]

**100% image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the track background by set `minimumTrackTintColor` and `maximumTrackTintColor` into `UIColor.clear` and draw the track background yourself.

For example:

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.size.height / 2).cgPath
        context.addPath(path)
        context.fillPath()
    }

}
```

Comment: didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Here some quick solution

You have changed frame of the line, the height is higher the default and that's why you see it.

You can move little bit slider at the 100%.

```
override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
    if value > 0.99 {
        rect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x+2, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
    }
    return rect
}
```

Or you can make the thumb bigger to cover the corners, its up to you.

Comment: but why is it ok while  (>1 value <100) ?

Comment: I replaced your 0.99 with 99

Comment: sorry i've used default settings for minimum and maximum value. And its 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: let normalizedValue = value / maximumValue
        if normalizedValue > 0.98 { solves this

Answer (score 0):

Original answer here: [Thumb image does not move to the edge of UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520940/thumb-image-does-not-move-to-the-edge-of-uislider/44194508)

updated to swift 4.2:

```
override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
    let unadjustedThumbrect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
    let thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide:CGFloat = unadjustedThumbrect.size.width / 2.0
    let minOffsetToAdd = -thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
    let maxOffsetToAdd = thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
    let offsetForValue = minOffsetToAdd + (maxOffsetToAdd - minOffsetToAdd) * CGFloat(value / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue))
    var origin = unadjustedThumbrect.origin
    origin.x += offsetForValue
    return CGRect(origin: origin, size: unadjustedThumbrect.size)
}
```

Comment: the edges are still there. Nothing changed

Comment: Strange, works fine for me, have you implemented this code inside your `UISlider` subclass?

Comment: Yes, also I implemented track rect. Value Max is 100 not 1

Comment: Ok, i changed to 100 and still working, what `trackHeight` are you testing it with?

Comment: with 14. Do I see it right that I have to mimimize the frame of my slider so that there is space for the thumb which needs more space now?

Comment: No it does not minimize the frame of your slider, instead it takes the center of the thumb to move by a certain offset